# jsonb and numeric precision and scale

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json

I'm using a `jsonb` column, where the JSON documents contain large integers (PostgreSQL 9.5). I've noticed that when the value stored has too many significant digits, it gets truncated.

As an example, I insert this into my table:

```
{"value": 7598786232076607106}
```

And when I select back the same row, I get:

```
{"value": 7598786232076607000}
```

[According to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html), numeric fields in jsonb are stored using the standard `numeric` type from postgres, and `numeric` normally allows:

> up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point

Is it possible to actually get this behavior with `jsonb`, instead of truncation?

Comment: `numeric` isn't `jsonb`. In jsonb you're just storing structured text, not binary or decimal numbers. Can you show the query that produces this so we can see the actual origin of the issue?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I was talking about a numeric field in a JSON document stored in a ``jsonb`` column. Basically, I insert: ``{"value": 7598786232076607106}``, and when I select back, I get ``{"value": 7598786232076607000}``. The documentation says numeric values in ``jsonb`` are using the standard ``numeric`` type from postgres.

Comment: Please show full, complete SQL example.

Comment: Actually, I think that's a rendering problem with PgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 5):

The issue wasn't with PostgreSQL itself, but with pgAdmin 4, which apparently is not capable of parsing JSON properly, and truncates the response from PostgreSQL.

I will be using a different tool from now on.

Comment: Please report a bug too.